# Hopper Disassembler AArch64 assemble instruction syntax error

Tags: arm, hopper, macos, aarch64

[image]

As the screenshot shown above, I attempt to change `cbz` to `cbnz`, hopper gives me "syntax error".

At this moment I can only change it by editing the instruction encoding in hex view as a workaround.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you contacted support?

Comment: You should select the who assemble instruction first.